# How to send POST data, including JSON, from iOS app to webserver

Tags: ios, json, post

Since I'm new to iOS developing, I need your help..

I need to send POST data from an iPad app to a webserver that will process the data.
In HTML it would be easily done by a form like this:

```
<form name="myform" action="myphpfile.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="input1" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="input2" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="json" value="{"a":"1","b":"2"}" />
</form>
```

As you can see I have two "normal" input and one containing a json formatted array of values.

How can I send the data in my app and handle the json in the right way to avoid issues?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [NSURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It exposes the HTTPMethod fields and HTTPBody. You'll want to encode your JSON as NSData and set it as the request body, your HTTPMethod will be "POST", obviously.